# Manage pool HttpClient and HttpResponse in a multithreaded environment because code get stuck and threads get killed

Tags: java, connection-pooling, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am working on a high performance code with multithreaded environment. We are working on a project where we have to crawl data from SharePoint. There are 10 crawler threads which fetch list of documents in SharePoint and add those items to a Queue.
There are 200 pool threads running (in parallel with the 10 crawler threads) which works on items in Queue to collect data of the items. One thread works on one item in parallel. All the threads are making API calls. Currently we are using CloseableHttpClient and PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager and creating an Object of CloseableHttpClient and Object of PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager each time for an API call. These 200 threads make 3 API calls. There is a lot of throttling in SharePoint, so we are making all threads to sleep and retrying API calls (after 40 seconds of sleep) using same httpclient which was used for the first call.
Now in the above scenario for On-prem SharePoint code works fine for 5,00,000 data crawls because there is no throttling in On-prem. But the threads get killed somewhere on running performance test in online sharepoint for more than 40,000 data(Sometimes at 1,00,000 and sometimes at 2,00,000). There is no error or exception. Just the threads stop abruptly and do not come again. Is it because of retrying? What could be the efficient way to manage the client and pool?
Crawler threads complete their task way before. So, they were not running when pool threads were stuck.

Tried to close Httpclient and pooling manager every time I create one in finally block. But that also stuck.